# BuildFire - Using the datastore from a server

Tags: buildfire

I am currently designing a plugin for BuildFire that requires syncing to be done between a Microsoft CRM service and BuildFire.  For this to work, I need to be able to update the BuildFire datastore from my own server that I will register with the CRM for the purpose of syncing these changes.  I have only ever used the buildfire library provided in the SDK to communicate with the datastore from the client.  Is there any way to communicate with the datastore from my server?

I see that there is an API key that is provided to my account.  Is that something that I can use for this purpose, and if so, how do I use that with the existing library?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not server to server API to the DataStore. While fundamentally you could mimic the same REST API calls made by the client. However, there is no guarantee that these API's wont change on you. Since they are not the official Public API, no notice will be given about changes, no backward compatibility will be attempted, nor is there any versioning. That being said, there is a Public API that is being built for enterprise accounts. You may speak to your Technical Account Manager to learn more.